# Drupal 7: VBO and Rules Component to update Node fields

Tags: 7, views, rules

I have a content type called 'Course' with subpages. In one of the subpages, a view is displayed. The view displays the node information of content type 'Learning object'. By Views Bulk Operations, I'm able to send the nids of selected rows of the view to Rules Component. But, what I want to do is store the nids of selected rows in a field of 'Course' type node in which that view is present. How can I send the nid of the page in which view is displayed to Rules Component?